# Tapping between UITextFields in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

When a `UITextField` is selected and has a keyboard shown, if I tap other parts of the view the keyboard disappears.

If I tap another `UITextField`, the keyboard stays up, the first textfield is deselected, and nothing happens. Then I need to tap on the other `UITextFIeld` again for selection to happen and a keyboard to appear.

Is there a way to make a second UITextField immediately accessible when a first `UITextField` is selected?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: You can have a next button as your return button, and in the delegate, when it is tapped, make the second UITextField first responder.

Comment: Stefan - this is not normal behavior (you should be able to verify this by creating a basic single view app with 2 text fields).  Something in your code is causing this behavior.

Comment: I don't have any code to dismiss the keyboard. I am using a TPKeyboardAvoidingTableview (cocoapod), which is the only thing I think might affect this. I'll try and create a minimum failure here and track this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reload the tableview in `textFieldDidEndEditing`, you'll break selection in this way. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

try it, press another view should call below fn.

```
-(void)disappearKey{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

after keyboard disappear, Tap any textfield, will appear keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think its a bug that the keyboard is not dismissed and opened again when tapping on another UITextField or UITextView.  It should be reported and Apple should fix it.

Using the textfield delegate methods and registering for keyboard notification it should be possible to manually keep track if the user tapped on another textfield and the keyboard did not close and reopen.  At the very least you should be able to detect when this is happening and close the keyboard manually by [textField resignFirstResponder];

The keyboard notification are as follows:

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
```

I'm''pretty sure you know the UITextfield and textview delegate methods

```
 – textFieldShouldBeginEditing: 
 – textFieldDidBeginEditing:
 – textFieldShouldEndEditing:
 – textFieldDidEndEditing:
```

I am not in an active project at the moment so I'm not sure if I just ignored the problem but I can't recall this happening to me.

Comment: I'll try this out tonight. I'm fairly certain "DidEndEditing" isn't firing when the second textfield is tapped, but the keyboard stays up that has my accessory done button.

Answer (score 0):

- you can use [BSKeyboardControls](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls). just see the demo and decide to
  use or not.
- or you can do you have to set tag in sequence to the each textfield
  in uiview. then use the below code.

  ```
  -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField

  {
       NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;

       UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

       if (nextResponder) {

      [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];

      } else {

      [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
  return NO; 
  }
  ```

Comment: It's not necessarily the next textfield. I have 8 on screen, and any single one is a valid target that needs to be tappable.