# tapping on another uitextfield does not close the keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have multiple uitextfields on a View and in this mehtod:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

I am calling:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

But it does not hide the keyboard when switching between UITextfields, I want to close it because some UITextfields open other views.

I have checked all events are firing.

I have seen this answer here but it doesn't help:
[Tapping between UITextFields in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002638/tapping-between-uitextfields-in-ios7)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the text field for which you're trying to dismiss the keyboard has its delegate set to the class that implements -textFieldDidEndEditing?

Comment: Also, are you running this on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: oh yes its that method is firing....If I tap on one field and then tap away keyboard hides but If I tap on another field while the keyboard is open then it it does not hide even though the textFieldDidEndEditing is getting called...the problem is happening on both iPad and iPhone

Comment: Can you share the code that sets the delegate on those text fields? Or do you use Interface Builder to wire up the delegates?

Comment: When the method fires for the second text field (the one that doesn't dismiss the keyboard) are you certain that the text field parameter in -textFieldDidEndEditing is the text field you think it is?

Comment: Why would you call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field parameter of the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method? The `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is only called when the text field resigns being the first responder. So calling `resignFirstResponder` at that time is pointless.

Comment: thanks maddy valid point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close keyboard by hitting specific textfield, give a tag to that textfield and implement its delegate method like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == 1)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```